# How to avoid keyboard popping out while navigating to next screen?

Tags: flutter, dart

When I navigate from LoginScreen() to HomeScreen() the keyboard pops up for no apparent reason for a split second and then immediately closes while the navigation is in progress.

The function that calls for the screen pushReplacement:

```dart
    () async {
                      if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                        final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
                        try {
                          await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
                              email: email, password: password);
                        } catch (e) {
                          Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                            content: Text('Email or Password are incorrect'),
                          ));
                        }

                        _user = await _auth.currentUser();

                        if (_user == null) {}
                        if (_user.isEmailVerified == true) {
                          Navigator.of(context)
                              .pushReplacementNamed(HomeScreen.routeName);
                        } else
                          Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                            content: Text('Validate your email pls!'),
                          ));
                      }
                    },
```

and the HomeScreen():

```dart
    import 'package:final_login/screens/loginscreen.dart';
    import 'package:final_login/services/auth.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

    class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
      static const routeName = '/home-screen';
      @override
      _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
    }

    class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(),
          body: Center(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                RaisedButton(
                  child: Text('Log out'),
                  onPressed: (){
                    AuthService().signOut();
                    Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed(LoginScreen.routeName);
                  },
                ),

              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

---

Solved by putting `FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());` before the function call.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Update:

The below answer is no longer the best way to do it after flutter update, this is the better way now:

`FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();`

## Old answer

try this, it will remove the keyboard programmatically before pushing new page:

```
if (_user.isEmailVerified == true) {
  FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
  Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed(HomeScreen.routeName);
}
```

Comment: note: FocusNode() must dispose. lake memory.

Answer (score 0):

Upper answer did not work for me. Just try this code before the navigation.

**FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();**

```
RaisedButton(
    onPressed: () {
    FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
    Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
    MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (context) => HomeScreen(),
                                    ),
                                  );
                                },
                              ),
```